# jPlayer - Safari not receiving headers on play - unable to buffer correctly

Tags: php, safari, jplayer

I am using jPlayer to play media, I am also using a PHP download script to deliver the content to jPlayer.

I am having an issue with Safari whereby the audio doesn't buffer correctly. Originally thinking this was an Accept-Ranges issue, I ensure the correct headers were being passed.

In firefox, as can be seen in the screenshot below, the headers get passed through fine, and everything works as I'd expect.

[image]

However, in Safari the following happens when I click play:

[image]

As you can see it called the download script, but the status remains pending and doesn't change. The strange thing is, the audio plays fine.

Upon looking at the headers received, it stumped me even further, as it appears there were no headers being sent:

[image]

These are the headers I am sending from my download script, bits omitted:

```
...

header("Content-Type: ".$mimeTypes[$ext]);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Test - '.$_GET[title].'.mp3"');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
$begin  = 0;
$end    = $fsize - 1;

if (preg_match('/bytes=\h*(\d+)-(\d*)[\D.*]?/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches))
{
    $begin  = intval($matches[1]);
    if (!empty($matches[2]))
    {
        $end    = intval($matches[2]);
    }
}

header('Content-Length:' . (($end - $begin) + 1));
header("Content-Range: bytes $begin-$end/$fsize");
```

My javascript to send the file to jPlayer is:

```
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "/download.php?track=" + id });
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
```

If anybody could point me in the right direction, whether I am missing some crucial header info that Safari requires - or ...?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I am having the exact same issue.

Comment: I switched my project to JW Player and no longer have this problem. I don't know if it was a specific jPlayer bug or my implementation. If you're struggling I can post my revised download code? Looking at the code in my original post, it doesn't look like I changed much though! If you manage to resolve this issue I would love to hear how!